# Map out unique results in DropDown select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm dynamically filling a select dropdown from a JSON array of objects and want to select by tag. The problem is I'm getting back duplicate results because multiple results can have the same tag.
How do I only display unique tags and not show duplicates?

Example I'm getting:
Honda
Toyota
Toyota
Volvo
Volvo

Example I want:
Honda
Toyota
Volvo

```
<Select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={handleSelect}>
  <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>
    Filter By Tag
  </option>
  {equipment.map((equip, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={equip.tag}>
      {equip.tag}
    </option>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter out the unique values before your return statement and then just iterate through them. You could use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to convert the array to list of unique values and transform it back to an array.

```js
const tags = ["Honda",
  "Toyota",
  "Toyota",
  "Volvo",
  "Volvo"
]

const unique = [...new Set(tags)]

console.log(unique)
```

Comment: Thanks. This set me on the right path (no pun intended). I forgot to mention that it's a JSON array of objects and apparently can't use "Set" because the objects are the same.  So, I found this answer: ` let unique = [
    ...new Map(
      equipment.map((equipment) => [`${equipment.tag}`, equipment])
    ).values(equipment.tag)
  ]; `

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new unique array and then use a map function on it and display them in your select fields.

```
render(){
    const brands = ['Honda',
      'Toyota',
      'Toyota',
      'Volvo',
      'Volvo'];
      const uniqueBrands = Array.from(new Set(brands))
  

  return (
    
  <>
  <select>
  {uniqueBrands.map(unique=>
  <option value="DEFAULT">
           {unique}
  </option>
  )}
</select>    
  </>
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**There are multiple ways, We can solve the above proble.**

> 1. Using Set

```js
let brands = ['Honda',
'Toyota',
'Toyota',
'Volvo',
'Volvo'];

console.log([... new Set(brands)])
```

> 2. Write a function

```js
let brands = ['Honda', 'Toyota', 'Toyota', 'Volvo', 'Volvo'];

function uniqueBrands(brands){
  let uniqueBrand = [];
  for (let brand of brands) {
    !uniqueBrand.includes(brand) && uniqueBrand.push(brand);
  }
  console.log(uniqueBrand);
}

uniqueBrands(brands);
```

**Note: Set Performance is better in case of long Arrays.**

Answer (score 0):

One approach is using **Set**,

```
let brands = ['Honda',
'Toyota',
'Toyota',
'Volvo',
'Volvo'];

const uniqueTags = [...new Set(tags)]
```

Another approach is using **filter**:-

```
const uniqueTags  = tags.filter((c, index) => {
    return tags.indexOf(c) === index;
});
```